# Function Return void How to Run with Open RIA Domain Service

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, devart

I have few Functions & Procedures to Run from Silverlight project. I have mapped data in EF6. Now I want to Run these function Using OpenRIA Service. I tried giving annotation like Query, Update, Insert, Delete. One or other function does some of these operations. Few return nothing & Few return data. 
I wrote a method to call 1 Function from RIA Domain Service

```
 public void BuildRoute4Rdinv(decimal? hpmsyear, string errorout)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.BuildRoute4Rdinv(year, ref errorout);
    }
```

What Annotation I should provide in above case. this function doesnt return anything & Have no complex type associated with. [Query] requires Return IEnumarable so i cant provide that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the one you are after is "[Invoke]"
Annotate your function with [Invoke] then a related method will be generated on your client side.

Comment: When I apply [Invoke] I'm getting compile time error :  Error 1 Operation named 'BuildRoute4Rdinv' does not conform to the required signature. Parameter types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of entities or complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types. Delasoft.RiaClient.UserService

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257694/alternative-to-using-an-entity-as-a-parameter-to-an-invoke-method-in-wcf-ria-ser